# How to add/edit code snippets in jupyer notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, code-snippets, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I tried to follow the instructions given in the README file of the extension.
Im using Windows and to open my notebooks I use the jupyter-notebook.exe stored in the directory

> ..\Anaconda3\Scripts

Within the Anaconda3 directory I go to the subdirectory

> Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_contrib_nbextensions\nbextensions\snippets

and there change the code of the file "snippets.json" from

```
{
"snippets" : [
    {
        "name" : "example",
        "code" : [
            "# This is an example snippet!",
            "# To create your own, add a new snippet block to the",
            "# snippets.json file in your jupyter data directory under nbextensions:",
            "# $(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions/snippets/snippets.json",
            "import this"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

to

```
{
    "snippets" : [
        {
            "name" : "example",
            "code" : [
                "# This is a test if something changed",
            ]
    ]
}
```

Then I restart my notebook and insert the example snippet. But my changes weren't adopted, I still get the original example snipped.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Be aware there are many files "snippets.json" and you need to find that one which the server uses.  You have probably changed not the right file. Detailed answer: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1279. For some users, the following path worked: C:\Programs\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Anaconda, you don't necessarily need to go searching for directories. There is a template embedded in the "Nbextensions" tab.

- Check "Snippets Menu" box
- Scroll down to 'Parameters' and check the "Include custom menu...JSON string below" box
- Insert whatever sample snippet you want
- Refresh your notebook

Check out one of my snippets:

```
{
    "name" : "My favorites",
    "sub-menu" : [
        {
            "name" : "import packages",
            "snippet" : ["# import various packages"
                   "import os"
                   "import scipy"
                   "import pandas as pd"
                   "import numpy as np"
                   "import seaborn as sns"
                   "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

                   "%matplotlib inline"

                   "# plot settings"
                   "from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters"
                   "register_matplotlib_converters()"
                   "plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000"]
        },
        {
            "name" : "TeX can be written in menu labels $\\alpha_W e\\int_0 \\mu \\epsilon$",
            "snippet" : ["another_new_command(2.78)"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, be careful with the quotations and commas. Additional help on that can be found [here.](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/snippets_menu/readme.html)

Answer (score 2):

In windows(os) jupyter notebook extension are hidden in programData folder (C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets)

To make changes in snippet just edit the snippets.JSON file accordingly:
[image]

Comment: This is the one that worked for my installation of jupyter notebook inside of Miniconda.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching in the wrong directory.

- In windows, run command `jupyter --paths` in anaconda prompt
  this will return the locations of `config:` `data:` & `runtime:`
- search for the file `snippets.json` in the `data:` locations
- in my case it is `C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets`

change and save the content in `snippets.json` and then restart your jupyter notebook
it will work!

Comment: I want to point out that ProgramData is a hidden system folder, thus it is not displayed in File Explorer.