# Jupyter Notebook Extension: Snippets menu is not working after enabling nbextensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-snippets, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

After I have installed nbextensions, I have enabled a few extensions such as Hinterland, Snippets, and Snippets Menu. The other extensions are working pretty fine, except for Snippets Menu.

I am not sure why the snippet menu tab is not showing, in which supposingly I should be able access the snippet codes of numpy etc from its drop-down menu.

I have tried multiple methods like reinstall nbextensions, refreshing my session, restarting the server, but noun of them work.[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyxM4.png)

Ideally it should appear as sth like this
[Snippets Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aIR2.png)

Comment: Welcome ! Did you go to `C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets` and change the `snippets.json` file and save it?

Comment: Hello thanks for checking! Since im using mac, i have changed the snippets.json file directly from the "Include custom menu content parsed from JSON string below" option. In this case do i still need to change the json file?

Comment: I am not sure about Mac, generally we change json in Windows.

Comment: oh sorry for my confusion, I am talking about "Snippets Menu" instead of "Snippets". Is it still the same case? Coz i saw online once the extension is enabled, they would automatically appear after i refreshed the notebook

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261170/how-to-add-edit-code-snippets-in-jupyer-notebook

Comment: thank you for your help! I followed the ins inside but it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if the problem you're having stems from the same I had earlier, but this might help.

I had everything up and running perfectly. I wiped and reinstalled Python to go to 3.10 for no real reason. Snippets_menu no longer showed. Not sure if other extensions flopped as a result. Dug around for hours trying to resolve or find a path to go down to no avail. Inspected notebook page in chrome. The point of the last blurb is to help others with similar issues know where to start looking.

**SOLUTION**:

snippets_menu seems to not load because there's an issue with the pandas sub_menu, thus breaking the whole thing. Go to, `\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\nbextensions\snippets_menu\snippets_submenus_python\pandas.js`, and enclose the stuff with single quotes (`label_count`, `label`, `label_mean`) to either double quotes or `\'` instead of singles.

To open the `AppData` directory, I usually enter `%appdata%` into the start menu. I.e. press Win key -> type `%appdata%` -> hit Enter key.

Everything here was in Windows context. Sorry Mac & Unix users. Maybe a comment from someone can add to this.